# websocket connection goes to unknown state

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, websocket

I have a web server running on `ubuntu` instance at `Amazon EC2`.
My web server is written in `Python` and supports `WebSockets`.

My Problem:

I am able to connect to my server through `websocket` and I am also able send and receive data over `websocket`. However, after few minutes if I try to send data on same connection from client application I am not receiving anything on server for the same established connection. Now if I close the client application or try to connect through another client application, I am able to connect and communicate again for few minutes only. And after few minutes the new connection again faces the same issue. Please help me to solve the issue.

Of course, when I run the server on my local testing environment the connection never dies and I can communicate over same `websocket` connection after hours also.

Comment: A few minutes, you say... I'm guessing it's about 15 minutes?

Comment: I have not exactly counted but its around 15 minutes.